# DragListener not working for recyclerview in nougat only

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-recyclerview, android-7.0-nougat, android-7.1-nougat

I have an issue with drag and drop functionality not working in Nougat while I drop an item on RecyclerView's item. **Its working fine in Pre-Nougat OS**. Only issue with RecyclerView's Item. I found one link [**Drag and drop target behavior changed in Nougat**](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=220923) I already post the question on this link but I dont get any answer till yet. I guess In this Link video file uploaded that will help you to understand [**behavior changes in Nougat**](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=220923).

Here I explain how I did drag and drop functionality.
In my case, there are two RecyclerView. First RecyclerView, horizontally scrollable and second vertically. First RecyclerView only for drag and Second RecyclerView only for a drop. Both RecyclerVieware inside ScrollView so, I disabled vertical scroll in second RecyclerView. **I added DragListener on Second Recyclerview's item**. Every item has drag listener so based on that I add/replace item while drop item. **I also added DragListener on One of TextView and that is working In Nougat**.
Below code I added on First RecyclerView's OnBindViewHolder.

```
 viewHolder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            ClipData clipData = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
            View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new CustomDragShadowBuilder(view);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                view.startDragAndDrop(clipData, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
            } else {
                view.startDrag(clipData, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
            }
            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/08/29/psa-drag-drop-behavior-change-Android-7p0.html